# Struggling to get number of chars in char*

Tags: c++, sizeof

```
char* string = "hello there";

cout << sizeof( string ); // prints 4, which is the size of pointer
cout << sizeof( *string ); // prints 1, which is the size of char
```

How do I get the number of characters contained in the string (11)?

Comment: I don't see either of those as dupes, although I'd be surprised if there wasn't a dupe _somewhere_ on SO (I couldn't find it with a cursory search). The first talks about the _size_ of a dereferenced char*, the second appears to deal with C++ _proper_ strings rather than char pointers.

Comment: @paxdiablo I am not totally convinced the second one is restricted `std::string`, newcomers to the language often aren't even aware of its existence.

Comment: @juanchopanza, when I see C++ strings without a qualifier of some sort, I tend to assume the proper ones, though you're right - a lot of the answers cater to both types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `strlen` you want for that, not `sizeof`. The first counts the number of characters up to the terminating NUL while the second gives you the size of the type which, in this case, is a *pointer* rather than the underlying array of characters.

By that last point, I mean:

```
char *x = "hello there";
char y[] = "hello there";
std::cout << sizeof(x) << ' ' << sizeof(y) << '\n';
```

will most likely output something like:

```
4 12
```

on a system with 32-bit pointers (and 8-bit `char`). In that case, the `4` is the size of the pointer, the `12` is the number of bytes in the array (including the NUL at the end).

In any case, that's moot, since `strlen()` is the right way to get the length of a C string (yes, even in C++, though you may want to consider using the C++ strings since they may save you a lot of trouble).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. By the way, I didn't know that strings in c++ ended in null aswell, I thought that was the case just in c.

Comment: @SkyPower, C++ strings (`std::string`) are different from C strings and you still have C strings available to you in C++. Those strings in your question (and my answer) are most definitely the C variety.

Answer (score 1):

The function `sizeof()` returns the size of a data type in Byte
For example because you define:

```
char* string = "hello there";
```

then type of `string` is `char *` and size of mostly all pointer is 4 Bytes ( this function returns 4)  But type of `*string` is `char` and size of every character is 1 Byte ( This function returns 1)
Solution for you :
Alternative 1:
Use function `strlen()` in library 'string.h'

Alternative 2:(from scratch)

```
int length = 0;
int index = 0;
while ( string[index] != '\0')
{
length++;
index++;
}
```

Comment: I'd be a little less "certain" that pointers are always four bytes but otherwise a good answer. Though I'm not sure why you have both `index` _and_ `length` in your code, that seems a little wasteful. You could just as easily do something like: `char *tmp = str; while (*tmp != '\0') tmp++; return tmp - str;`.

Comment: @paxdiablo : Yes, size of all pointer is not 4 bytes but size of most of them is 4 byte / 'index' is used to improve readablity

Comment: The size of most pointers on my platform is 8 bytes. And it is not a very exotic platform, it is just an x86-64.

Comment: @juanchopanza: My mean is in 32-bit based systems.

Comment: If everyone reverted to the mean, we'd all be eating McDonalds instead of real food, or listening to awful, androgynous boy bands, or reading autobiographies from 17-year-old girls who don't seem to have the concept that they haven't actually _lived_ a life worth telling yet :-)